# for loop problem

Tags: python, for-loop

For loop issue:

```
in1 = open('file_1', 'r')
in2 = open('file_2', 'r')
outf = open('out_file', 'w')


for line in in1:
    s = line.split('\t')
    A = s[1][:-1]
    B = s[0]
    counter = 0
    for line in in2:
        ss = line.split('\t')
        if A == ss[0] or A == ss[1]:
            counter += 1
    outf.write('%s\t%s\t%s\n'%(A,B,counter))
```

The problem is that it is only going through `for line in in2:` for the first `line in in1`.  I can't seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate over a file only once.  To start from the beginning again, use

```
in2.seek(0)
```

before the inner loop.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I deleted my answer...for some reason thought there could be a scope issue.

Answer (score 2):

The first time you loop over `in2`, you consume it. Either reopen it, or seek back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have read each line from file_2 in the inner loop then in2 is at end-of-file.  If you want to read file_2 for each line in file_1 then add:

```
    in2.seek(0)
```

just before or after the write.

Answer (score 0):

When working with files, please do this

```
with open('out_file', 'w') as outf:
    with open('file_1', 'r') as in1:
        for line in in1:
            s = line.split('\t')
            a = s[1][:-1]
            b = s[0]
            counter = 0
            with open('file_2', 'r') as in2:
                for line in in2:
                    etc.
```

Using `with` assures your files are closed.

Opening a file in the smallest enclosing scope guarantees it can be read all the way through.  It's costly to keep reopening the file, but there are a lot of ways to speed up this application.

Also, please use only `lowercase` variable names.  Reserve `Uppercase` for class names.